# How can we create a sized function trait in Rust?

Tags: rust

In the below code, to my understanding, `SimpleSpawner` should have a known size, since it is equivalent to a function pointer + a single `u8` value, but this code gives the error `the size for values of type` (dyn SimpleSpawner<for<'a> Output = u8> + 'static) `cannot be known at compilation time`. Ideally, I'd be able to use a function pointer, but function pointers and closures are not compatible in Rust.

([Rust Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=018a7fe6c35fd4557521b8b19c7f78b5))

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct RandomTable<T> {
    pub entries: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> RandomTable<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        RandomTable {
            entries: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

// pub type SimpleSpawner = fn(u8) -> u8;
// pub type SimpleSpawner = dyn Fn(&mut u8) -> u8;
pub trait SimpleSpawner: Fn(&mut u8) -> u8 + Sized {}


// changed from `-> RandomTable<SimpleSpawner>`
pub fn room_table(map_depth: i32) -> RandomTable<dyn SimpleSpawner> {
  RandomTable::new()
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't whether `SimpleSpawner` is `Sized`, it's that `dyn SimpleSpawner` (and `dyn Trait` in general) is always dynamically sized. You'll need to put it into some kind of `Box`.

Comment: yes, remove `+ Sized` on `SimpleSpawner` and return `RandomTable<Box<dyn SimpleSpawner>>`

Comment: Also: "function pointers and closures are not compatible in Rust" isn't true in general. All function pointers implement `Fn`, although not all `Fn` closures can be cast to function pointers (specifically if they borrow their environment, they can't).

Comment: Ah, great - that presents a dynamically sized solution ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f17312ff16625ad43e8b8bc335730dac)).

I'm also curious if it is possible to do this without boxing, since in principle, we do know the size of a function pointer + a `u8`.

Comment: @bbarker No we don't, `Fn` is **not** a simple pointer. It can have any kind of data attached. A simple pointer is `fn`.

Comment: Right, I was thinking of implementing a closure as a struct containing the closed data of fixed size as well as the function pointer. I think I sort of have an approach here ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9765598f578169dac103c3c6b1a79f29)), will have to see if works in my actual code tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: @bbarker Except that you still have `: Sized` as part of your trait, which is completely unnecessary, It is a very rare trait, so only use it if you need and understand it.

Comment: Good catch, thanks - I don't need it since I'm not using a trait object in the `RandomTable` (which needs `Sized` due to its usage of `Vec`, iirc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few misconceptions here.

> SimpleSpawner should have a known size, since it is equivalent to a function pointer + a single u8 value

`SimpleSpawner` is a **trait**. That means there is nothing known about its size, it could be a gigabyte-large struct that implements it. A trait simply means that a given type has certain functionality, it says **nothing** about its size.

The `Sized` trait **still** doesn't say anything about the actual size. It just says that, at compilation, the compiler now knows its size. There are many types that aren't sized, meaning, the compiler cannot argue about their size, and therefore they have to be interacted with through references (`&` references to unsized traits have a known size), or through `Box` (meaning that we moved them on the heap, so on the stack we don't care about their size any more).

> a function pointer + a single u8 value

I'm not sure where you get the "single u8 value" from - even if it were like that, it would be only a function pointer. The `u8` is a **parameter** that gets passed to it at runtime, it will not be part of the object.

> function pointers and closures are not compatible in Rust

That's partially true, but `Fn` is **not** a function pointer. What they refer to here is that **capturing** closures are not compatible with `fn` function pointers. In fact, every closure implements one of the `Fn` variants.

Here a quick recap:

- `fn` - A simple function pointer. It has zero references to the outside and is completely self-contained.
- `Fn` - A function type that can be called via reference. Can capture outside variables immutably.
- `FnMut` - A function type that can be called via mutable reference. Can capture outside variables immutably.
- `FnOnce` - A function type that can only be called by ownership, and it gets consumed upon call, so it can only be called once. Can perform actions (like variable consumption) that can only be done once.

Here is a pretty comprehensive example of all the possible combinations:

```rust
struct MyStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    fn immutable_action(&self) {
        println!("\t\tImmutable action!");
    }
    fn mutable_action(&mut self) {
        println!("\t\tMutable action!");
    }
    fn consuming_action(self) {
        println!("\t\tConsuming action!");
    }
}

fn run_functionpointer(f: fn()) {
    println!("run_functionpointer");
    // Can be called multiple times. Not compatible with capturing closures.
    f();
    f();
}

fn run_immutable(f: &impl Fn()) {
    println!("run_immutable");
    // Can be called multiple times and doesn't require `mut`.
    f();
    f();
}
fn run_mutable(f: &mut impl FnMut()) {
    println!("run_mutable");
    // Can be called multiple times, but requires `&mut`.
    f();
    f();
}
fn run_consuming(f: impl FnOnce()) {
    println!("run_consuming");
    // Cannot be called multiple times.
    f();
    // this would be a compiler error:
    // f();
}

fn main() {
    // Simple closure that doesn't reference any outside variables.
    // Compatible with `fn`, `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`.
    let mut simple_closure = || {
        println!("\tSimple closure!");
    };
    run_functionpointer(simple_closure);
    run_immutable(&simple_closure);
    run_mutable(&mut simple_closure);
    run_consuming(simple_closure);

    // Closure that captures one outside object via reference.
    // Compatible with `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`.
    // **not** compatible with `fn` because `fn` is just a simple pointer
    // and has no space to store the captured data.
    let captured_variable = MyStruct;
    let mut capturing_closure = || {
        println!("\tCapturing closure!");
        let val = &captured_variable;
        val.immutable_action();
        // Those would be compiler errors because they require mutability or ownership:
        // val.mutable_action();
        //val.consuming_action();
    };

    //run_functionpointer(capturing_closure); // ERROR: "closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables"
    run_immutable(&capturing_closure);
    run_mutable(&mut capturing_closure);
    run_consuming(capturing_closure);

    // Closure that captures one outside object via `mut` reference.
    // Compatible with `FnMut` and `FnOnce`.
    // **not** compatible with `Fn` because `Fn` cannot capture `&mut` references.
    let mut mutably_captured_variable = MyStruct;
    let mut mutably_capturing_closure = || {
        println!("\tMutably capturing closure!");
        let val = &mut mutably_captured_variable;
        val.immutable_action();
        val.mutable_action();
        // Would be compiler error because it requires ownership:
        //val.consuming_action();
    };

    //run_functionpointer(mutably_capturing_closure);
    //run_immutable(&mutably_capturing_closure); // ERROR: "closure is `FnMut` because it mutates the variable `mutably_captured_variable`"
    run_mutable(&mut mutably_capturing_closure);
    run_consuming(mutably_capturing_closure);

    // Closure that consumes an outside object.
    // Compatible with `FnOnce` only.
    // **not** compatible with `FnMut` because `FnMut` can be called multiple times.
    // But consuming the outside variable can only be done once.
    let owned_variable = MyStruct;
    let mut owning_closure = || {
        println!("\tOwning closure!");
        let mut val = owned_variable;
        // Everything is allowed, as we own the variable.
        // Note that `consuming_action` destroys `val`, however,
        // so this function can only be called once.
        val.immutable_action();
        val.mutable_action();
        val.consuming_action();
    };

    //run_functionpointer(owning_closure);
    //run_immutable(&owning_closure);
    //run_mutable(&mut owning_closure); // ERROR: "closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `owned_captured_variable` out of its environment"
    run_consuming(owning_closure);
}
```

```
run_functionpointer
        Simple closure!
        Simple closure!
run_immutable
        Simple closure!
        Simple closure!
run_mutable
        Simple closure!
        Simple closure!
run_consuming
        Simple closure!
run_immutable
        Capturing closure!
                Immutable action!
        Capturing closure!
                Immutable action!
run_mutable
        Capturing closure!
                Immutable action!
        Capturing closure!
                Immutable action!
run_consuming
        Capturing closure!
                Immutable action!
run_mutable
        Mutably capturing closure!
                Immutable action!
                Mutable action!
        Mutably capturing closure!
                Immutable action!
                Mutable action!
run_consuming
        Mutably capturing closure!
                Immutable action!
                Mutable action!
run_consuming
        Owning closure!
                Immutable action!
                Mutable action!
                Consuming action!
```

Comment: Sorry for wording this poorly perhaps, but in my defense - `SimpleSpawner` was more of a concept, as noted by various iterations of it being commented out; I was just trying to find a good representation in Rust. Thanks for the in-depth answer and comments.

Comment: @bbarker I would have loved to help you more for your actual goal, but you kind of really didn't explain what you were actually trying to achieve.